# Complex data structure syntax

Tags: arrays, json, object, data-structures, push

I have a `clubs` array, as follows:

```
    [
        {
            "name": "Arsenal",
            "codeName": "arsenal",
            "nickName": "Gunners",
            "dateFounded": "1886",
            "stadium": "Emirates Stadium",
            "manager": "Arsène Wenger",
            "squad": []        
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Aston Villa",
            "codeName": "aston-villa",
            "nickName": "Villans",
            "dateFounded": "1874",
            "stadium": "Villa Park",
            "manager": "Rémi Garde",
            "squad": []
        }
     // and so on...
    ]
```

...and I want to fill each empty `squad` array with the relevant data. In the case of AFC Bournemouth, I want to `.push()` the `bournemouth` array (see below) into the `squad` property of the `clubs` array:

```
[               
        {"firstName": "Artur",
            "lastName": "Boruc",
            "nationality": "pl",
            "position": "gk",
            "shirtNumber": "1",
            "age": "36"},

        {"firstName": "Adam",
            "lastName": "Federici",
            "nationality": "au",
            "position": "gk",
            "shirtNumber": "23",
            "age": "31"},
 // and so on...
]
```

Firstly, is this possible? And secondly, is this an advisable way to go about solving this problem, or is there a more efficient / better way to do it?

I want to be sure before I go head and compile all of the data.

Any help/advice would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You can just assign the array to the squad property of the respective team. If array in code sample 1 is A, and the array in code sample 3 is B then you can write A[2].squad = B;

Comment: Thanks. So, array 1 = clubData. Array 2 = bournemouthSquad. So in my controller (I'm using AngularJS) I would write clubData[0].squad = bournemouthSquad? I tried that and it broke the application... :/